# "manim: command not found". Un and Reinstalled Manim and now having issues

Tags: python, manim

```
/bin/sh: manim: command not found
```

From other answers I've found it seems to be an issue with path or directory? I'm not sure though and I don't want to make things worse. Does anyone know how to fix this? Mac user btw.

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing how exactly you (tried to) install it. Could you update your question with a bit more information?

Comment: I followed these https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/installation/macos.html directions

Comment: It's weird because I had it working fine yesterday and suddenly started getting that error. That's when I uninstalled and reinstalled everything and I'm continuing to get that error.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness: we resolved this question on [Manim's Discord server](https://manim.community/discord). The main problem was that the executables of anaconda's Python were not added to the system's `PATH`.

Resolution: either

- change the call to the executable `manim` to the module `python -m manim` (where `python` is the *correct* Python version), or
- add the `/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/bin` to the `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Manim Community Edition, there is a change from `manim` to `manimce`.

So on the command line, please use the following instead.

```
$ manimce
```

Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/74975758/20905930

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33546721)

Answer (score 0):

The anaconda path was in .zshrc but manim was not found. I added:
/Users/*username*/opt/anaconda3/*manimenvelope*/bin
to PATH and manim now works normally.