# "Command 'manim' not found" (Ubuntu)

Tags: manim

I'm using Ubuntu (version 22.04 LTS) and followed the installation doc from https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/installation/linux.html, but when I try to run the test code for scene.py CreateCircle, I get the following:

"Command 'manim' not found, did you mean:..."

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Test code (from https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/tutorials/quickstart.html):

```
from manim import *
class CreateCircle(Scene):
def construct(self):
    circle = Circle()  # create a circle
    circle.set_fill(PINK, opacity=0.5)  # set the color and transparency
    self.play(Create(circle))  # show the circle on screen
```

I ran this from the file directory in the terminal with:

```
manim -pql scene.py CreateCircle
```

(new to using Ubuntu)

Comment: What is the test code and how did you try to run it?

Comment: Added it in the edit

Answer (score 0):

By default, Ubuntu does not have Python's bin folder on the path. You'll have to use `python -m manim`, or find Python's bin folder and put it on the path.

Answer (score 0):

For ManimCE installation, there will be an executable 'manimce' in ~/.local/bin directory. So you could use 'manimce' instead of 'manim'.

```
manimce -pql scene.py CreateCircle
```

By the way, you could create a 'manim' soft link to it for convenience.

```
ln -s ~/.local/bin/manimce ~/.local/bin/manim
manim -pql scene.py CreateCircle
```